# How to setup Weppack to use materializecss with Phoenix 1.5 + Liveviews?

Tags: jquery, webpack, elixir, phoenix-framework, materialize

**Problem:**

I can not figure out how to embed [materializecss](https://materializecss.com) into default scaffolded Elixir/Phoenix 1.5 (incl. Liveview)-Project.

Every try to get it to work ends with errors. ie: jquery not found or similiar.
Even if I try to embed the js/css directly via cdn-links in the layout-files it does not work. I guess it is just a matter of a correct configuration of Weppack.

**Setup:**

I am on Windows with Elixir 1.9.4, Phoenix: 1.5, Webpack: 4.41.5

**Expected Result should be:**

A working result should achieve the following working:
[Side-Nav-Materializecss](http://archives.materializecss.com/0.100.2/side-nav.html)

So that I can call:
$("#my-menu").sideNav();

at the bottom of template or via liveview-hooks.

Comment: You can add the jquery reference in the template, that's the simple way.

Comment: ya, I tried this before, no luck

Comment: Are you trying to use it with liveviews? If so then, you'll have to write a custom hook to attach the jquery with your tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was finally able to solve it:

Steps to reproduce:

1. Scaffold a new phoenix-1.5-project with live-views enabled
2. Add packages to package.json:

   "jquery": "^3.6.0",
   "materialize-css": "^0.100.2"
3. Add entry in assets/css/app.scss:

   @import "~materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css";
4. Add entry in assets/js/app.js:

   import "materialize-css/dist/js/materialize.min"

---

For a **Liveview** you just add the specific hook in app.js, ie.:

```
Hooks.SetMyMenu = {
  mounted() {
      $("#my-menu").sideNav({
        closeOnClick: true
      });
  }
}
```

For a **Simple Template** you just add a script at the end of the template, ie:

```
  <script>
        window.addEventListener('load', function () {
            $("#my-menu").sideNav({
                closeOnClick: true
                });
            })
  </script>
```